# From where can I install Firefox with all other dependencies?

Tags: firefox, fedora, yum

OS is Fedora Core 3 i368, `yum` repository is remi. When I try to install Firefox from the above repository, `yum install firefox*`, the error says that `missing dependencies` and provides a list of packages that are missing.

What I honestly want to do is to `install firefox and all its dependencies automatically` from just one place. Can someone provide a good `repository name` from where i can get `firefox +` all its `dependencies`?

Comment: You should really upgrade. Fedora Core 3 is 6 (!) years old by now, and it's likely very hard to find some (working) repository for such an old version.

Comment: Can i use a redhat repository though?   @andri

Answer (score 1):

You might find packages suitable for FC3 from the [Fedora Archives](http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/).

Still, FC3 is 6 years old and has been unsupported for 5 years; the latest version is Fedora 14, so I highly recommend you upgrade.